# How to save the results of a for-loop to a vector in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I generated random numbers, and easily calculated their means. My question is, however, how can I see the numbers I generated? I'd like to save these numbers to a vector. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
import random

print ("#n\tmean")

for n in (1,10,100):
        sum = 0
        mean = 0

        for i in range(n):
                sum += random.random()
                mean = sum / n

        print ("%d\t%g\t" % (n, mean))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is a "vector"? Do you mean a list?

Comment: The term "vector" is not very appropriate in your context. Anyway, what you seem to need is to store a bunch of values in a single variable. For this purpose, you may use a list, or a numpy array if you want to do mathematical operations with them afterwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
import random

n = 100
l = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
mean = sum(l)/100
```

Comment: This is about as pythonic as it gets

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly, what I was looking for! How can I put this whole code in a loop? I mean, if n = (10, 100, 1000, 10000), how can I get l(i) lists (where i=1,...,len(n))?

Answer (score 4):

use a list to save all the results:

```
results = []
for i in range(n):
sum += random.random()
mean = sum / n
results.append(mean)
```

then get the output array by:

```
np.hstack(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this, if you want to avoid numpy.

```
import random

print ("#n\tmean")
meansList = []
for n in (1,10,100):
        sum = 0
        mean = 0

        for i in range(n):
                sum += random.random()
                mean = sum / n

        meansList.append(mean)
print meansList
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the numpy package

```
import numpy as np 

my_numbers = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
print np.mean(my_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try python's in-built data structure list which I think is closes to a vector and would work for you.

```
vector = list()

//in the for loop

    r = random.random()  
    vector.append(r)
```

Also note that lists can append lists since you have two for loops. For example you can do something like

```
outer_vector.append(inner_vector)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the mean of random for 1, 10, 100 in one line using list comprehension:

```
import random

result = [(n,sum(random.random() for _ in range(n))/n) for n in (1,10,100)]


print(result)
```

one possible output:

```
[(1, 0.1269484085194036), (10, 0.6572300932440089), (100, 0.4796109974064649)]
```

`random.random() for _ in range(n)` is the generator comprehension that feeds `sum`, divide by `n` to get the mean, wrapped in an outer loop and creating tuples with value/mean